# what is the difference between itlb_misses.miss_causes_a_walk, itlb_misses.walk_completed, and itlb_misses.walk_pending

Tags: perf, perf-event

I ran

```
  perf stat -e itlb_misses.miss_causes_a_walk,itlb_misses.walk_completed,itlb_misses.walk_pending  grep Hecuba  /storage/nvme6/complete_shakespeare_4096_times
```

and got

```
 Performance counter stats for 'grep Hecuba /storage/nvme6/complete_shakespeare_4096_times':

            27,732      itlb_misses.miss_causes_a_walk                                   
            13,492      itlb_misses.walk_completed                                   
         1,048,087      itlb_misses.walk_pending                                    

       0.252038252 seconds time elapsed
```

So obviously these three are all different.  The actual workload I'm running perf against is not important in that whatever workload I run relative values for the counters are similar.

I know why a miss would cause a walk, but the above seems to imply that not all walks complete. Why is this?

Also why are the pending walks so much greater than the caused walks?

And finally if I want to understand the itlb miss rate, which of the above counters should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counters are [described as follows](https://oprofile.sourceforge.io/docs/intel-skylake-events.php):

> 0x01: (name=miss_causes_a_walk) Misses at all ITLB levels that cause page walks
> 0x10: (name=walk_pending) Counts 1 per cycle for each PMH that is busy with a page walk for an instruction fetch request.
> 0x0e: (name=walk_completed) Code miss in all TLB levels causes a page walk that completes. (All page sizes)

A page walk can fail to complete if the desired page isn’t actually described in the page tables; a page walk reaching a “not present” page is counted as a failed page walk (and results in a page fault if it wasn’t speculation).

The pending walks counter doesn’t reflect an instantaneous number of pending walks; it counts the number of cycles spent walking pages.

To calculate the iTLB miss rate, you’d typically use the first counter (in relation to the total number of iTLB queries).

See also [details about page table walks in multi-level paging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59641957/4500798).